# Where can I see a reasonably complete skeleton of a Mammoth?

Tags: museums

I was just watching some documentary about ice age animals, and I was wondering if there is a museum somewhere that displays reasonably complete skeletons (and/or full-size models) of Mammoths, sabre-tooth tigers, etc.

Ideally it should be not far from London.

Comment: Did you try the Natural History Museum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all I would check the [Natural History Museum](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/) in London. They have a Mammoth skeleton hidden behind a Whale in the mammals section. They also have sabre tooth (Smilodon) somewhere around.

[image]

The second best address, would be the "[Muséum national d'Histoire Naturelle](http://www.mnhn.fr/le-museum/)" in Paris. It has a HUGE hall full of skeletons, with several Mammoth models.

[image]

There are at least 2 complete Mammoth Skeleton in the back of the hall:

[image]

Then there is the "Naturhistorische Museum" in Vienna, Austria (Museum for nature history). It has a quite extensive collection of [complete skeletons](https://www.google.com/search?q=naturhistorisches%20museum%20wien%20saurier&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=rBOjUenaK8ntiAeB54GoBw&biw=1760&bih=872&sei=sBOjUefFAa6RigfioIHIAw#um=1&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&hl=en&authuser=0&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=naturhistorisches%20museum%20wien%20skelett&oq=naturhistorisches%20museum%20wien%20skelett&gs_l=img.3...22188.23203.0.23401.7.7.0.0.0.0.58.230.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.14.img.beu1fVXymVA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.aGc&fp=4611966ef7e4e675&biw=1760&bih=872). They do not seem to have a Mammoth skeleton in particular but instead a model of a complete animal, with fur etc.

Here is the similodon skeleton from there:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While someone finds one closer to London, the [La Brea Tar Pits museum](http://www.tarpits.org/) in Los Angeles have awesome and quite complete skeletons. As you may infer from the name, in this area tar pits have caused animals that sank into them to remain [remarkably intact](http://www.tarpits.org/page-museum/exhibits). The museum is near La Brea road which means *tar* and excavations for more remains are ongoing.

Comment: Guess somebody does not like the La Brea Tar Pits? :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a french winery acquired a Mammoth skeleton to attract customers.

This is the [Cave des Vignerons - Histoire Naturelle](http://s333221838.onlinehome.fr/site/index.php?lang=en). It is located in South of France, near Nîmes.